# The requested URL /generate/5r4reia5b7 was not found on this server

Tags: php, apache

I just recovered a project about a wishcard system but I'm lost because I have a server error.

Everything works well on MAMP (on my local server) but not on a DEV server

On DEV server I got :

```
The requested URL /generate/5r4reia5b7 was not found on this server
```

I don't know anything about server.

I got an `.htaccess` file like this

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^generate/(.*)$ generate.php?hash=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^send/(.*)$ send.php?hash=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^view/(.*)$ view.php?hash=$1 [L]
```

When the user click on a button to generate a wishcard, the url is : http://www.example.com/generate/5r4reia5b7

```
function generateRandomString($length = 10) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}

<button id="go">Create my card</button>

$("#go").click(function( event ) {
    saveAction('btCreateCard');
    window.location = '/generate/<?php echo generateRandomString() ?>';
});
```

Can I have some help please? What's wrong between the php code/.htaccess? Is it because of the server configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Add [RewriteBase Directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteBase) on top of your `.htaccess`

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase "/"

RewriteRule ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately I have the same error

Comment: check that mod_rewrite is enabled in your server via `phpinfo()` or `apachectl -l`

Comment: Yes `mod_rewrite` was already activated on the server